# Firestore: Data modelling for activities / feed / timeline

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, data-modeling

I'm trying to find a suitable Firestore data model for some kind of activity feed for my application.

**Example:**

- A user from company A creates new task and assigns it to a user of company B.

**Requirements**:

- Users should see activities based on their company_id and user_role_id
- Every activity affects at least two companies (sender and receiver)
- Users should be able to archive activities. If a user archives an activity, it is archived for this particular user only. Other users can still access this activity until they archive it for themselves.

**Current state:**

```
// data model: activities collection
affected_companies: Array,
affected_user_roles: Map,
description: String

// Example
affected_companies:['c1', 'c2'],
affected_user_roles: { '2': true, '5': true },
description: 'Task A1'
```

Info: because we can't use multiple `array-contains` operators and I have a limited amount of `user_role_ids`, I simply use the field names for `affected_user_roles`.

Querying this collection is quite easy:

```
let company_id = 'c1';
let user_role_id = '2';

// Query activities based on given company_id and user_role_id
db.collection('activities').ref
  .where('affected_companies', 'array-contains', company_id) 
  .where('affected_user_roles.' + user_role_id, '==', true)
```

**Problem: How to query only non-archived activities?**
As described above users should be able to archive an activity for themselves (= hide it from their feed).

**Approach 1:**
Practically I would simply add another array to my `activity` documents with all `user_ids` who have archived the activity for themselves. I would then add `.where('core.archived_by_users', 'array-contains', user_id)` to my query. Although this does not work. Multiple `array-contains` are not allowed.

**Approach 2:**
I also thought about doing it similar to `affected_user_roles`: use the user_ids as field names and set boolean values. Although I would need to query for documents where a value does not exist, which is impossible as far as I know:

```
// Using user_ids as field names
archived_by_users: { '111': true, '241': true }

// Does not work because field 'archived_by_users.557' does not exist.
let user_id = '557';
.where('archived_by_users.' + user_id, '==', false)
```

**Approach 3:**
Using a subcollection `archived_by_users` in every `activity` document where I would store the `user_id` of each user who has archived the activity. Although it's not possible to query documents based on a value in their subcollection.

I did not come up with a good solution. What would work is:

- Filter on client-side (not really an option since the activity feed will grow to thousands of documents. The goal is to fetch only the non-archived ones)
- Add another collection `users_activities` which keeps track of the `activities` archived by users. Although this would require additional queries and probably won't save me any reads.

Can anybody think of a good approach here? Every answer is welcome. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you considered tracking the id's of the activities inside the user's collection? This way you can have the array of user activities along with archived ones and then filter the ones you are showing.

Comment: If you only have 2 companies involved, I'd break them into their own fields:
`sender_company` +
`receiver_company`

That way, you can use simple equality and avoid the `array-contains` on that field.

Comment: @mdobrucki that's something I'm thinking about, yes. Although I would still need to query all activities and filter them on the client side afterwards. Once this feed grows (think about 1000s of activities) it can get problematic.

Comment: @CDoe Every user has one company assigned. On the activities page I fetch all data which fits to the current user and its company. Because a company can be sender or receiver, I would need sth like a logical 'OR' (which doesn't exist in Firestore) because I would need to query sender or receiver company.